# Mono debugging from VS.2010 to Linux ubuntu

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging, mono

we are looking into VS tools for mono, but under documentation i cannot find any related info how to install mono server for remote debugging on linux server.

Also it does not say wheather this is a gui or commandline app... We are not running GUI on any of the linux boxes..

Linux is Ubuntu 12.04 LTS has the latest mono distro...

So is it possible to achieve to install mono debug server on a console only system and how?

Thank you,
Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the past, it is possible to set it up using Mono Tools for Visual Studio

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7fbae0bb-7ddf-498d-8a2a-73f96b72d749/

http://www.mono-project.com/GettingStartedWithMonoVS

However, after the Novell to Xamarin transition, this extension seems to be inactive for a while.

Before any Mono developers comment, you might have to resort to MonoDevelop.